# Dropbox http api Get shared link for file after shared link already created by its path

Tags: dropbox-api

Is there a way to get link to file after i created it with create_shared_link_with_settings ?

That means , i want to get the link to the file in another time after the creation of the link, and at that time i have only the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can retrieve the shared link again using [/2/sharing/list_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links).